# VB SQL UPDATE command returns error "Runtime error 424: Object required."

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, dao

Here's the code:

```
Dim tr As Transactions
Set tr = New Transactions

Dim ID As Integer
Dim name As String, username As String, password As String, activate As String

name = cmbName.Value
ID = tr.GetUserID(name)

If (AccountActivated = True) Then
    username = txtUsername.Value
    password = txtPassword.Value
    MsgBox name & " " & username & " " & password
    activate = "Yes"
Else
    username = ""
    password = ""
    activate = "No"
End If

tr.UpdateAccount name, username, password, activate 'ERROR HERE: Object required
```

---

Here;s the function I'm calling:

```
 Public Function UpdateAccount(ByVal name As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal activation As String)
        Call connectDB
        sSQL = "update User set Username = '" & username & "', Password = '" & password & "', AccountActivated = '" & activation & "' where Name = '" & name & "'"
        MsgBox sSQL
        db.Execute sSQL
 End Function
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receive?  And, you should definitely be using `Parameters` for binding the values of `username`, `password`, `activation`, and `user`.

Comment: Runtime error 424: Object required

Comment: What's the syntax for that so I could try? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why here you use "db" and on the other question "CurrentDb" ? Always code using option explicit.

And why is function, change to sub, i don't remember if this could cause a problem.

But most important, dont use text inputed from text boxes to build a sql string, this makes it easy to be a victim of SQL injection, use parameters.

Comment: If you change from Function to Sub, the line turns red. Also, how do I do the parameters then for the SQL? Thanks!

Comment: sorry.. guess dao dont support parameters, you would have to use a recordset. other way is cleaning the string striping possible sql injection code like apostrophes

Comment: But your "Object required" is probably a wrong variable name. Turn on Option Explicit and you should see it.

Comment: Oh, problem solved! I just had to change 'db' to 'CurrentDb' :)